# Is there a World completion chest?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I had heard murmurs of people saying there is a chest when you get 100% World completion. As I got the last vista before getting 100% World completion, I was disappointed to find that I didn't get a chest. Did my game bug out or is there not actually a chest for world completion?

The Guild Wars 2 official wiki does not offer any information on this.

Here is an image of what my World Progress looks like:

[image]

Comment: I believe you have to go to a certain spot after achieving 100% complete: try the Chantry of Secrets in Bloodtide coast.

Answer (score 5):

After you have achieved 100% world completion, you must go to the Chantry of Secrets (Order of Whispers HQ) in the Blood Tide Coast to claim your rewards.

Comment: For future readers, at some point after this post it became no longer true. I acheived 100% world completion in late 2014 and received my rewards immediately in WvW.

Answer (score 1):

The 100% world completion chest requires you to get all vista's, skill points, points of interests and renown hearts in both the PvE and the WvW map. Make sure you have completed the WvW map, as most people tend to forget this one, or don't realise that it is part of the requirement.

Comment: I have complete both the PvE and WvW maps and when I go to the map, it says 100%.

Comment: Also, can I assume from your answer that there is suppose to be an world completion chest? You didn't say that explicitly and that is kinda what I asked.